# PyDev - unable to import modules which are under sub directory

Tags: python, pydev

I have a python project structure shown below,

```
├── example
    ├── test.py
    └── module
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── mymod.py
        └── submod.py
```

I imported above project into a pyDev project and `test.py` could not import `mymod`.
I was importing module inf following way.

```
from module import mymod
```

I added `module` directory to pyDev `PYTHONPATH` but that did not hep.

I could run the `test.py` from console without any problem.

Comment: Tested your directory structure, an `import module` in `test.py` has no problem to load and execute `module/__init__.py`. You are going to have to show some code, your description is not enough to diagnose your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Add `example` to the python path

Answer (score 0):

As @Giacomo d'Antonio said, you have to add 'example' to the PYTHONPATH (and if you had added 'module' to the PYTHONPATH you should also remove it).